# Retrieve data from a firestore - Firebase - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, data-retrieval

i am having a problem retrieving data from my firestore application ..
i have a map of map of strings in each document of the Snapshot and i don't know how to retrieve it .. i tried to search but found nothing ..

can anyone help ?!

i can't post images so here it is link for the hierarchy of the data base

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tmNrg3Ce6WBv5XIlARPSVKCiK_dkawnr

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 (although your image does not show code, the rationale discussed there is applicable here as well) and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: i looked .. unfortunately my photo purpose isn't for showing the code it is for showing the database itself .. i didn't how to write it so i took a screenshot of it .. 
i learned that my Title isn't as obvious as it should be so i will fix it next time .. Thank you ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use DataCollection and let the FireStore handle the ID or for this particular problem .. if we assumed you had a QuerySnapshot snapshot

```
snapshot.documents.forEach((doc){
  doc.data.forEach((k,v)//at which k is key and v is value 
  {
    print('${k}: ${v}');
    object obj = new object();
    obj.setObj(v['1'] ?? '',v['2'] ?? '',v['3'] ??'');
    objectList.add(obj);
  });
});
```